# Use of module 'CALayer' as a type

Tags: swift, calayer

I want to port ITSwitch from obj-c to swift. https://github.com/iluuu1994/ITSwitch.git

in ITSwitch.m

```
@property (readonly, strong) CALayer *rootLayer;
```

so in swift I write:

```
var rootLayer:CALayer?
```

but code give me this error:

```
Use of module 'CALayer' as a type
```

What's the error mean?
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you add `import QuartzCore` at the top of your `.swift` file, the error will go away. The error message itself seems like a bit of a bug.

Comment: Thanks, it works. it seems this question is so easy. I should do more research and solve by myself